# Access localhost(wamp) with other device

Tags: php, apache, wamp

We know that if we open wampmanager in windows, we can access to localhost with enter `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in browser

But if we want to access it in other device (mobile or tablet), we cannot enter `localhost` in browser.

So we enter the IP that wamp is running on.

Example `192.168.1.2:80`

But when I use this IP in browser, I cannot see localhost.

I changed IP in `httpd.conf`, but it is not working.

Comment: Make sure wamp is set to online and your mobile device is on the same wifi network

Comment: *"I cannot see localhost"* – what *do* you see instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling Windows firewall. If that works, open port 80 in the firewall settings and reenable.

Comment: I have disable firewall and can access localhost Thanks